# How can I get the length of an edge of an object using it's index and snap them together using GN

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

How can I get the length of an edge of an object using it's index and snap them together using GN.

Example:

My goal is to have:

1. Geometry Nodes generate a smaller box with the same height as another objects edge length, which is acquired from the objects edge index (**in the yellow color located at index 4**)
2. Have their vertices snap together.  See image below.

[image: img1]

But I'm having trouble with getting the edge length correct.  I tried 2 different ways see image below.

[image: img2]

And

[image: img 3]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one works by capturing your target solid's edge-vectors, edge-lengths, and edge-normals, before converting its edges to points, and instancing a unit-cube on the points.

the unit cube is offset by .5 in X and Y, before instancing, so one of its vertical edges is on its origin.

The captured attributes are then used to scale and orient the cube.

[image]

You can select the target edge in the modifier interface, and adjust the spin of the cube around it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Important node is here the transfer attribute node so that the position is from the group input node (the "original cube").